# Redirect user to last viewed page in hook_menu

Tags: php, drupal

I have implemented hook_menu in order to set a $_SESSION var that stores the current stylesheet preference for users. Once it's set, I'd like to redirect users back to the previous page they were viewing. How can I get the value of the previous url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer - [referer_uri()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/referer_uri/6) returns the value I need and drupal_goto() will do the redirect.

So to redirect a user back to the previous page: drupal_goto( referer_uri() )

Answer (score 1):

Drupal's referer_uri() is the way to do it, but be careful using this function, as it relies on php's HTTP_REFERER. HTTP_REFERER is not a reliable variable, as it is often not set. For more information check out : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php